# AIDataService cannot be applied

Tags: java, android

```
 final ai.api.android.AIConfiguration configuration = new ai.api.android.AIConfiguration("Client access token", AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,

           ai.api.android.AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);

    aiService = AIService.getService(this, configuration);
    aiService.setListener((AIListener) this);

    final AIRequest aiRequest = new AIRequest();
    final AIDataService aiDataService;
    aiDataService = new AIDataService(configuration);
```

The error is in the last line of the code.
i.e :- `aiDataService = new AIDataService(configuration);`
the error says -

'**AIDataService(android.content.Context, ai.api.android.AIConfiguration)' in 'ai.api.android.AIDataService' cannot be applied to '(ai.api.android.AIConfiguration)'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused because **AIDataService** does not have any *context* in its syntax. To resolve the problem

declare

```
private Context context;
```

and

```
context = getApplicationContext();
```

now the syntax will be

```
final AIDataService aiDataService = new AIDataService(context, configuration);
```

Now there will be no error and it works fine.